# What does "Resident of any country excluding" mean?

Tags: terms-of-service

You need to be a resident of any country excluding: a, b, c.

Does that mean you need to be a resident of any country not listed or do you need to be a resident of any country that IS listed?

This is for a company that is based in a country that is listed as being excluded. So i find it weird that they would exclude their own country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It reads as if you need to be a resident of a country that is not a, not b, and not c.

If this is in a terms-of-service policy, it may be that this is a terms-of-service policy for a company based in country a that would need to comply with different regulations if it provided its services to people who lived in that country. This would be an unusual business model but is one example of a situation where the above language could arise.

It is also possible that the document says something other than what the writer intended.

Comment: Further, there may be separate terms of service conditions for domestic customers v. international customers that haven't been mentioned here. "To make use of Product X you must be a citizen of Country C, D, E ... To make use of Product X2 you must not be a citizen of (countries C, D, E etc.)".